# Which default IdentityType type does the UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity use?

Tags: c#, .net

UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity has two overloads. One of these do no specify an IdentityType (but the other does).

Which default IdentityType does this overload actually use underneath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it searches all identity types.  Of course this means it could find multiple matches in which case a `MultipleMatchesException` is thrown.

ETA: Confirmed that it does search all of them.  Digging into the [code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/c79de0509785d6d126806c39bd67769efdd280a3/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/AD/ADStoreCtx_LoadStore.cs), around line 605:

```
                // This is the tricky case.  They didn't specify a UrnScheme, so we need to
                // try all of them.

                string[] urnSchemesToTry = new string[]
                {
                    UrnScheme.SamAccountScheme,
                    UrnScheme.UpnScheme,
                    UrnScheme.DistinguishedNameScheme,
                    UrnScheme.SidScheme,
                    UrnScheme.GuidScheme,
                    UrnScheme.NameScheme
               };
```